# Could not start a new session. Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am new to automation. Trying simple Selenium POC. Below is the webdriver configuration details

JDK version 17.0.2
Selenium version 4
Chrome browser version  98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chromedriver version is the same

This is my code:
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/login");

I did setproperty. Please find attached screenshot.

error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:576)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:245)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:48)
at automationFramework.FirstSeleniumClass.main(FirstSeleniumClass.java:17)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'ASG602977', ip: '192.168.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:226)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
... 7 more

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6nBD.png)

Answer (score 0):

**For Local execution you can use webdrivermanager .
pls refer below Link to know the Implimentations.**

[WebDriver Manager Video Link](https://youtube.com/watch?v=WzPPS247kKQ)

**Below is the Solution for Selenium 4 Grid Execution on Mac Remote Machine.**

Please add chrome driver into the Path.

Download the Compatible chromedriver :
https://chromedriver.chromium.org

Go that Location:
First Run:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine chromedriver
```

Then move ChromeDriver:

```
sudo chmod a+x chromedriver && sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

While registering the Node you can use flag `--detect-drivers true`

Comment: Hi Tahir, My code has just two lines                              
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");  
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();                                                     if i execute above two line i get Failed to load the library from temp directory: C:\Users\REKHA~1.SUB\AppData\Local\Temp\IEDBB11.tmpException in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96oxggEIzEA

pls follow this